# Replace the value with "X" with same number of length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one input field with value : `<input id="newfield" value="12345" />`

Value of input can be vary and may contain the different length.

I want to replace the whole value if i click on button
 `<a href="#">button<a>`

Value of `id="newfield"` is dynamic and input come from client side.

It may be 10 , 5 anything.

For example :
use type value - 123123456789

I want it like - xxxxxxxx6789

If user type value - 12345, I want it like - x2345

**Note : open for jquery and js both**

Comment: Can you post an example or be more clear?

Comment: do you want masking some x number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### jQuery

```js
$('#mylink').click(function(){
  var value = $("#newfield").val();
  // make a string with x-characters
  var x = new Array(value.length - 3).join('X');
  // join this string with the tail of the value, and replace it
  $('#newfield').val(x + value.substr(value.length - 4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="newfield" value="12345"/>
<a href="#" id="mylink">button</a>
```

### Vanilla JS

This uses the same internal code for altering the string, but doesn't use jQuery. Simply add the function to the link:

```js
function changeInputValue() {
  // get the value
  var value = document.getElementById("newfield").value;
  // make a string with x-characters
  var x = new Array(value.length - 3).join('X');
  // join this string with the tail of the value, and replace it
  document.getElementById('newfield').value = x + value.substr(value.length - 4);
}
```

```html
<input id="newfield" value="12345"/>
<a href="javascript:changeInputValue();">button</a>
```

Comment: i want X but with same number of length

Comment: @SachinRawal I'm sorry, I took the last 5 characters instead of the last 4.

Answer (score 3):

Convert value to string then loop based on length to replace each character with "X".

```
// input value "hello world"
var value = $("#input").val().split(""),
    newVal = '';

for (var i = 0; i <= value.length - 4; i++) {
    newVal += "X";
}
```

Based on your update, loop again through *value* array to add last 4 characters.

```
for (var i = value.length - 4; i <= value.length - 1; i++) {
    newVal += value[i];
}

$("#input").val(newVal);
// new value "XXXXXXXXorld"
```

See it [working](http://jsfiddle.net/wLu73tqr/3/).

Comment: somebody hates jQuery. :) +1

Comment: OP didn't indicate to use jQuery. This can be done without jQuery. Why add the dependency if it's not necessary? Edit: *now* OP indicated jQuery is fine.

Comment: @CamilStaps OP is open to any solution. Not to mention, the question is tagged with jQuery.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the start, but yes, you're right. Although, looping through the array may cause performance problems on longer strings and older machines.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your button is:

```
<a href="#" id="button1">button</a>
```

if you are using jquery:

```
$("#button1").click( function()
    { 
       var old_val = $(#newfield).val();
       var last_part = old_val%10000;
       var front_part = Array(old_val.length-4+1).join("X"); // to insert N Xs, we require `Array(N+1).join("X")`
       $("#newfield").val(front_part + last_part) ;
    });
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: But you can use jQuery for this. It's more proper using jQuery, than using inline javascript in my opinion. Also syntax is more simplistic and readable.

Comment: Agreed that jQuery isn't needed for this, but the question was tagged with jQuery so a jQuery-based answer is acceptable here.

Comment: You're right in using jQuery then, but looking at the update this doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="getValueFromClient()">button<a>

<script>
function getValueFromClient(){

// write ajax call or something which will fetch value from client and assign back to input field.
var valueFromClient=10; // write code to fetch value
$("#newfield").val(valueFromClient);

}


</script>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: +1: for the unnecessary downvote. the question is tagged jQuery. And you really dont need jQuery for anything. Its a JavaScript library only

Comment: Inline event handlers generally aren't a great practice.

Comment: I really don't know why Camil is downvoting these answers. I always asume jQuery just "a better and more simplistic" syntax (and many more off course) than standard core JavaScript.

Comment: You're right in using jQuery then, but looking at the update this doesn't answer OP's question.